# How to view Google Groups access logs?

Tags: security, logging, workspace, audit, group

We are using Google Workspace Enterprise Standard plan for our company emails. Recently we found out that in some of our groups the "*conversation history*" setting was set to "on" and the "*who can view conversations*" setting was set to "entire organization" which caused all the conversations to be archived in the group and non-members of the group (but members of the organization) to be able to view these conversations.

Google creates group pages in the form of https://groups.google.com/a/**companydomain.com**/g/**groupname** So if any member of the organization visits this page (intentionally or accidentally) he/she can view all the conversations.

Having noticed that, we turned off the necessary access settings but we want to audit who accessed these conversations during a certain period.

We tried "*investigation tool*" under "*security center*" with using "groups enterprise log events" and "groups log events" as data sources but had no success. These data sources only provide "group creations" and "member additions to/removals from groups".

Any idea how to view the access logs for the https://groups.google.com/a/companydomain.com/g/groupname page and the conversations in it? Or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.